# How can I change config file path in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I use Codeigniter framework , and you know when I try to load a config file then use it

I do something like that :

```
$this->load->config('myconfig', TRUE);
```

myconfig.php file is located inside application folder ( application/config/myconfig.php)

and use it like this :

```
 $this->config->item('get_item', 'myconfig')
```

My question is : how can I change the location of myconfig file and use it properly ?

I want to put the config file(s) in out folder like this :

- mysite -> system(folder)
- mysite -> user_guide(folder)
- mysite -> myConfigFiles(folder)
- mysite -> myConfigFiles(folder) /  myconfig.php

I need to do something like this :

```
$this->load->config(base_url.'myConfigFiles/myconfig', TRUE);
```

any help ?

Comment: I don't believe you can, why would you want to?  There might be a better solution to your problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes - it is possible to do this. The loader will accept `../../relative/paths`. You can use a path relative from the default config directory (an absolute path will not work).

So let's say you have this structure (had a hard time following your description):

> - mysite
>
>   - application
>
>     - config <-- default directory
>   - system
>   - myConfigFiles
>
>     - myconfig.php

You can just do this:

```
$this->load->config('../../myConfigFiles/myconfig', TRUE);
```

This works for pretty much everything - views, libraries, models, etc.

---

Note that with the introduction of [the `ENVIRONMENT` constant](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/environments.html) in version 2.0.1, you can automatically check for config files *within the config directory* in another directory that matches the name of the current environment. This is really intended to be a convenience method for loading different files depending on if you are in production or development. I'm not 100% sure what your goals are, but this additional knowledge may also help you achieve them, or it may be totally irrelevant.

Comment: Wesley Murch , thank you very much , yes it's work fine now , sorry for the description on my question , I'm not English native =) .. thanks again for your last note , It helps me so .. have a nice day =)

Comment: Be aware that with the second parameter set to `TRUE`, variables declared in your config file will be stored in an array index corresponding to the path you provide in the first parameter. You will need to use `$this->config->item('../../myConfigFiles/myconfig');`

Answer (score 2):

Really not sure WHY you would want to do this (and I wouldn't recommend it), but since all config files are is regular PHP files you can put a config file in the standard location that loads your extra config files. As an example:

```
mysite -> application -> config -> myconfigloader.php
```

then in `myconfigloader.php` put this:

```
<?php

require_once(APPPATH.'../myConfigFiles/myconfig.php');
```

So once you do

```
$this->load->config('myconfigloader', TRUE);
```

It will load everything in your `myconfig.php` file. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thank you Femi , your way works fine but it will not help me , I need to load config file depends on a var that come from the Url , like this : $this->load->config('myconfigfiles/'$varFromUrl, TRUE); .. thank you for your help ..

Comment: Sure thing. I will say that whatever it is you are trying to do you should really really really reconsider letting a request parameter directly dictate your choice of configuration file: there are definitely better choices for almost any problem that could be solved with that technique.

Comment: You are right , I just want it easy for the end user to customize the script , so I want to put all config files on out folder with out digging inside application and config files , coz I need to change config , language and also view folder for every Model , so I want to grab all these stuff in one close folder and let the user create and change config and folder easily .. that is the point , I know maybe there are better ways to do that , but I cannot think more than this way /:  thanks for your time ;)

Comment: Nice idea! Thumbs up