# changing config file path in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

My folder is structured like this:

> - root folder
>
>   - config
>
>     config.php
>   - MySite
>
>     - system
>
>       - application
>       - config
>           config.php

Within application folder is the config.php file, I have modified it so that it loads the config file from config -> Config like this from the root directory:

The config file works fine if I leave the config file in its native directory application -> config -> config.php but as soon as I try to lead it from root folder -> config -> config.php, it throws up the following error:

> ```
> An Error Was Encountered
>
> Your mysite/system/application/config/config.php file does not appear to contain a valid configuration array.
> ```

Any idea why this is happening, and how I can resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130234/how-can-i-change-config-file-path-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

Leave the config file in it's default directory and it will work.